# Keep nulls with two IN()

Tags: arrays, postgresql, join

I'm refactoring very old code. Currently, PHP generates a separate select for every value. Say `loc` contains `1`,`2` and `data` contains `a`,`b`, it generates

```
select val from tablename where loc_id=1 and data_id=a;
select val from tablename where loc_id=1 and data_id=b;
select val from tablename where loc_id=2 and data_id=a;
select val from tablename where loc_id=2 and data_id=b;
```

...etc which all return either a single value or nothing. That meant I always had n(loc_id)*n(data_id) results, including nulls, which is necessary for subsequent processing. Knowing the order, this was used to generate an HTML table. Both data_id and loc_id can in theory scale up to a couple thousands (which is obviously not great in a table, but that's another concern).

```
           +-----------+-----------+
           | data_id 1 | data_id 2 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
| loc_id 1 |     -     |  999.99   |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
+ loc_id 2 |   888.88  |     -     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

To speed things up, I was looking at replacing this with a single query:

```
select val from tablename where loc_id in (1,2) and data_id in (a,b) order by loc_id asc, data_id asc;
```

to get a result like (below) and iterate to build my table.

```
Rownum  VAL
------- --------
1       null
2       999.99
3       777.77
4       null
```

Unfortunately that approach drops the nulls from the resultset so I end up with

```
Rownum  VAL
------- --------
1       999.99
2       777.77
```

Note that it is possible that neither data_id or loc_id have any match, in which case I would still need a `null, null`.

So I don't know which value matches which. I ways to match with the expected loc_id/data_id combination in php if I add loc_id and data_id... but that's getting messy.

Still a novice in SQL in general and that's absolutely the first time I work on PostgreSQL so hopefully that's not too obvious... As I post this I'm looking at two ways to solve this: `any in array[]` and `join`s. Will update if anything new is found.

### tl;dr question

How do I do a `where loc_id in (1,2) and data_id in (a,b)` and keep the nulls so that I always get n(loc)*n(data) results?

Comment: "I don't know which value matches which" - you wouldn't know even if there were NULLs. you haven't specififed an `order`.

Comment: Correct, I did not specify it in the above. I would have an an order by loc_id asc, data_id asc.

Comment: Is `(loc_id, data_id)` defined unique in your table? (Meaning you have at most 4 entries without NULL values.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in a single query with two steps:

1. Generate a matrix of all desired rows in the output.
2. `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to actual rows.

You get **at least** one row for every cell in your table.
If `(loc_id, data_id)` is unique, you get **exactly** one row.

```
SELECT t.val
FROM        (VALUES (1), (2))     AS l(loc_id)
CROSS  JOIN (VALUES ('a'), ('b')) AS d(data_id) -- generate total grid of rows
LEFT   JOIN tablname t USING (loc_id, data_id) -- attach matching rows (if any)
ORDER  BY l.loc_id, d.data_id;
```

Works for *any* number of columns with *any* number of values.

For your simple case:

```
SELECT t.val
FROM  (
   VALUES
      (1, 'a'), (1, 'b')
    , (2, 'a'), (2, 'b')
   ) AS ld (loc_id, data_id) -- total grid of rows
LEFT   JOIN tablname t USING (loc_id, data_id) -- attach matching rows (if any)
ORDER  BY ld.loc_id, ld.data_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where (loc_id in (1,2) or loc_id is null)
and  (data_id in (a,b) or data_id is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the fields you use for filtering, so you know where the values came from:

```
select loc,data,val from tablename where loc in (1,2) and data in (a,b);
```

You won't get `null`s this way either, but it's *not a problem* anymore. You know which fields are missing, and you know those are `null`s.

Comment: Yeah that would be the "I ways to match with the expected loc_id/data_id combination in php if I add loc_id and data_id... but that's getting messy." I was thinking of. 

Hoping to avoid this but if it's the only way...